# parse html table using htmlagilitypack on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

I am able to get the html code of a webpage,using html agilty pack.
 code is this.

```
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='fixTable']");

for(int i = 0; i < table.Count; i++)
 {
   string text = table[i].InnerHtml;
   //txtblk.Text = doc.Load(text);

    var htmlConcat = string.Format("<html><body>{0}" +"</body></html>",text);

  }
```

now, I want to display, this entire table on windows phone screen. 
I dont know much about windows phone, 
so shall I use TextBlock? 
i had no luck with it.

Like we do in asp.net, asigning data table to grid, is there any simple way out? 
like shall we use any Grid control?

while debugging, if i select text and view it using html visualisers, its perfect what i want . but i dnt know hw to display in windows phone and in what...

Answer (score 0):

So your actual question is "*how to display html in windows phone?*". And the answer is to use `WebBrowser` control. Put a `WebBrowser` control in your application page, then in the code you can simply call `NavigateToString` method to display html string in the control :

```
webBrowser1.NavigateToString(htmlConcat);
```

Resources on this topic is also widely available on the internet, [this is](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx) one of them.

**UPDATE :**

I think i get what you are after.

> "*Like we do in asp.net, asigning data table to grid, is there any simple way out?*"

Unfortunately, As far as I know there is no simple way to do that in windows phone or any XAML based application. Asp.Net translate your code to HTML, so it is easy to append HTML string to asp.net page. XAML is not HTML, so you have to find a way to translate HTML elements to XAML controls which will not be an easy task.

Comment: I dont want to use web browser. I want within my application with some control.
Even I tried this,
     var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "fixTable")
                .Elements("tr")
                .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray())
                .ToArray();

But I dont know in which control I should put this.

Comment: check [HTML2XAML](http://html2xaml.codeplex.com/) from codeplex, maybe it can help you